# htaccess rewrite regex rule - insert dash and period in query string

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't seem to figure out this specific regex htaccess rewrite, and could use some assistance.  I'm trying to go from this:

> mysite.com/product/13202102/any-random-product-name

and rewrite to this url:

> mysite.com/product.php?id=13-2021.02

Note that the id will always have exactly 8 numbers, and will always require a dash (-) after the first 2 digits, and a period (.) before the last 2 digits.  The tailing string is irrelevant, but I'd like the url to work with or without a trailing slash (/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^/?product/([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})/? /product.php?id=$1-$2.$3 [L]
```

Comment: Great thank you!  Although now my CSS, images, and links on the page don't work, even after adding RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
and RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d , or trying RewriteRule ^(|css|images|) - [L]

Comment: Update: I added / to the beginning of my paths and it fixed it.  So instead of <img src = "pic.png"> it's <img src = "/pic.png">.  Anything wrong with doing that?

Comment: Hmm, I guess doing that breaks my ability to test on localhost.  So instead I changed to ./pic.png and ./style.css, which works on both, but then once again the htaccess rules prevent the css, js, images, and links from working correctly.  Help much appreciated.

Comment: @Erich You can also fix the relative/absolute linking by adding a `<base href="/">` (or whatever the proper URI base is) in the header of your pages. It's not the rules that's preventing the load, it's just changing the URL base (by adding more path nodes, e.g. `/13202102/`) breaks all relative URLs.